# Switching JFrame but there is a Flashing Screen

Tags: java, jframe

How to switch between 1 JFrame to another JFrame without flashing screen? what is the code to switch? I use this code to switch...

```
JFrame2 ref = new JFrame2();
ref.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false)
```

yes it runs and switch to JFrame2 but the problem is the screen is flashing when it switch to JFrame 2.

Comment: How about don't. Instead use a `CardLayout` to change the view in the current frame

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes I did it but my problem now is that my JFrame is very heavy because there are a lot of swings inside and I need to make another JFrame were I will restore some of my swings(label, text field, buttons) so, in this case, I need to make another JFrame that switching each other.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make your custom `JPanel` and update it rather than using a new `JFrame`.

Split and group your swing components in to `JPanels` and then call

> panel.revalidate();
>
> panel.repaint();

you might also want to set

> panel.setDoubleBuffered(true); // for smooth transition.

see [Oracle's doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered(boolean)) for more information.

Here is a simple example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(300, 300);
    
    File file = new File("src/stackoverflow/index.png");
    customPanel pane = new customPanel();
    pane.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    pane.setImage(ImageIO.read(file));
    f.add(pane);
    f.setVisible(true);
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    file = new File("src/stackoverflow/index1.png");
    pane.setImage(ImageIO.read(file));
    pane.repaint();
}

static class customPanel extends JPanel{
    BufferedImage image;
    
    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```